# How i put Ubuntu on an USB?

Tags: 13.04, usb

I already downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 32-Bits, and Universal USB installer, i have ubuntu on Winrar as downloaded but when searching for the ISO to Install it to my USB doesnt appear.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your file is shown as a Winrar file, because you have ISO files associated with Winrar, or you don't have an ISO program.

All you have to do is run Universal USB installer, choose Ubuntu 32bit from the drop down list, and then browse to the downloaded file, and choose it.

Once you choose it, you will notice that its an ISO file, as seen in step 2.

[image]